# Php parse error ''

Tags: php, jquery, html

please can someone help me correct the error below. I am trying to echo div tag with `onclick` attribute from a JavaScript file. please how can i correct this am just a beginner, thanks

```
<?php 
    echo '<div onclick="$('.mob-top-menu').slideToggle('fast');" class="mob-menu-button"></div>';
?>
```

this is the error I got when I ran the code

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '').slideToggle('' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<div onclick="$(\'.mob-top-menu\').slideToggle(\'fast\');" class="mob-menu-button"></div>';
```

Comment: thanks a million, am really grateful

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
echo '<div onclick="$(".mob-top-menu").slideToggle("fast");" class="mob-menu-button"></div>';
 ?>
```

Comment: you forgat '.mob-top-menu' part

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mBogaz

Comment: thanks guys, am so grateful, its work good now